# Initialization Vector Exception

Tags: android, security, exception, encryption

I am suppose to built an array of bytes using this elements in this order:

- A symmetric encrypted AES key (with a random key for AES 128, random Initialization Vector for AES 128. Encrypted using AES 128 in CBC mode and PKCS5 padding. Before encryption the text is codified in UTF-8)
- AES IV
- Encrypted message (using RSA algorithm in ECB mode and PKCS1 padding, previous generated key and the public key of the message recipient)

What I am doing is getting the length of each parameter, in order to create the new byte []. Then in a for loop I try to add the three elements in order.

```
public void encrypt(String original)
{
    SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();

    byte [] key = new byte[16];
    byte [] iv = new byte[16];

    sr.nextBytes(key);
    sr.nextBytes(iv);

    Cipher cipher;

    try 
    {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        IvParameterSpec IV=new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES"), IV);
        byte[] utf8 = original.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte []encryptedAES = cipher.doFinal(utf8);

        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(128);//128 bits
        KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();

        Cipher publicKeyCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
        publicKeyCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kp.getPublic());
        byte [] encryptedRSA = publicKeyCipher.doFinal(encryptedAES); //error here

        int length1=encryptedAES.length;
        int length2=IV.getIV().length;
        int length3=encryptedRSA.length;
        int length=length1+length2+length3;
        byte [] result= new byte[length];

        int l=0,m=0;

        for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            if(i<length1)
            {
                result[i] = encryptedAES[i];
            }
            else if(i>=length1 && i<length2)
            {
                result[i] = IV.getIV()[l];
                l++;
            }
            else if(i>=length2)
            {
                result[i] = encryptedRSA[m];
                m++;
            }
        }
        Log.i("Encrypted", "done");
        this.encryptedMessage=Base64.encodeToString(result, false);
        Log.i("Encrypted Message:", this.encryptedMessage);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the exception that I am getting is:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA block
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently your IV has to be 16 bytes, and not 128 bytes. (128 bits = 16 bytes)

Comment: Thank you @Quanturium, you are right I should express it in bytes and not bits. Will check if it works and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: If it solved your problem, could you set this topic as fixed ?

Comment: Hi @Quanturium, now I am getting a new exception. Could you kindly have a look at it? I have edited my question

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace ?